# In app billing Android non-consumable items

Tags: android

I am creating an Android app in which I want to sell some videos by using in-app Billing. I added in-app billing and it is working but if I buy a video and exit the application the video becomes again paid means I need to buy it again. So I want, if one user buys a video he can watch it always. Here is my code. Thanks.

```
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.MediaController;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.LoadControl;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelection;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlaybackControlView;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
    import com.zeeshan.echoshow.util.IabHelper;
    import com.zeeshan.echoshow.util.IabResult;
    import com.zeeshan.echoshow.util.Inventory;
    import com.zeeshan.echoshow.util.Purchase;

    import org.w3c.dom.Text;

    public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private MediaController vidControl;
        TextView description;
        ImageButton mPlayButton;
        TextView movienamedetails;
        TextView movieCategory;
        ImageView imageCover;
        TextView movieDuration;
        Button purchasebutton;
        TextView movieYear;
        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
        private final String STATE_RESUME_WINDOW = "resumeWindow";
        private final String STATE_RESUME_POSITION = "resumePosition";
        private final String STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN = "playerFullscreen";

        private SimpleExoPlayerView mExoPlayerView;
        private MediaSource mVideoSource;
        private boolean mExoPlayerFullscreen = false;
        private FrameLayout mFullScreenButton;
        private ImageView mFullScreenIcon;
        private Dialog mFullScreenDialog;
        ListView list;
        private int mResumeWindow;
        private long mResumePosition;
        TextView freepaid_check;

       String ITEM_SKU_temba1="com.qshow.temba1";
       String ITEM_SKU_temba2="com.qshow.temba2";
        String ITEM_SKU_temba3="com.qshow.temba3";
        String ITEM_SKU_Arab_Twit="com.qshow.arabtwit";
        String ITEM_SKU_Dinar="com.qshow.dinar";
        String ITEM_SKU_Khaybar="com.qshow.khaybar";
        String ITEM_SKU_Malhamat_Ghadr="com.qshow.malhamatghadr";
        String ITEM_SKU_Malhamat_Dhad="com.qshow.malhamatdhad";
        String ITEM_SKU_Soukout_Khilafa="com.qshow.soukoutkhilafa";
        String ITEM_SKU_Swalef="com.qshow.swalef";
        String ITEM_SKU_Malhamt_Sakhra="com.qshow.malhamtsakhra";

        String ITEM_SKU=null;
        String movie_name;
        private static final String TAG1 =
                "InAppBilling";
        IabHelper mHelper;
        private Button buyButton;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    //        Intent intent = getIntent();
    //        final String[] parts_array = intent.getStringArrayExtra("parts_array");
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mResumeWindow = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_RESUME_WINDOW);
                mResumePosition = savedInstanceState.getLong(STATE_RESUME_POSITION);
                mExoPlayerFullscreen = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN);
            }
            if (mExoPlayerView == null) {

                mExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
                initFullscreenDialog();
                initFullscreenButton();
                final Intent intent = getIntent();
                final String[] parts_array = intent.getStringArrayExtra("parts_array");
    //            final int[] parts_images_array=intent.getIntArrayExtra("parts_images_array");
                description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_description_detail);
                imageCover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagecoverdetails);
                movienamedetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movienamedetails);
                movieCategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moviecategorty);
                movieDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movieDuration);
                movieYear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moviedate);
                buyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buyButton);
    //            clickButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
    //            clickButton.setEnabled(false);
                int image = intent.getIntExtra("image", 0);
                String desc_detail = intent.getStringExtra("description_details");
                 movie_name = intent.getStringExtra("moviename_details");
                String movie_category = intent.getStringExtra("movie_category");
                String movie_durationz = intent.getStringExtra("movie_duration");
                String movie_time = intent.getStringExtra("movie_year");
                String free_or_paid=intent.getStringExtra("free_or_paid");
                freepaid_check = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_freepaid);
                // String vidAddress = intent.getStringExtra("movie_links");
    //            Custom_Parts_Adapter adapter = new Custom_Parts_Adapter(DetailsActivity.this, parts_array, image);
    //            grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_parts);
    //
    ////            if(!free_or_paid.equals("paid"))
    ////            {
    ////                grid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ////                freepaid_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ////
    ////            }
    //            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    //            grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   view,
   Intent(DetailsActivity.this, PartVideo.class);
    //                    startActivity(intent1);
    //                   // Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "You Clicked on " +parts_array[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Custom_Parts_Adapter adapter=new Custom_Parts_Adapter(this, parts_array, image);
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                if(!free_or_paid.equals("Free"))
                {
                    list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    buyButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        int action = event.getAction();
                        switch (action) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                                break;

                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                                break;
                        }

                        // Handle ListView touch events.
                        v.onTouchEvent(event);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(DetailsActivity.this, PartVideo.class);
                        intent.putExtra("episode_url",parts_array[position]);
    //                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

    //            int image = intent.getIntExtra("image", 0);
                String vidAddress = intent.getStringExtra("movie_links");
                imageCover.setImageResource(image);

                description.setText(desc_detail);

                movienamedetails.setText(movie_name);

                movieCategory.setText(movie_category);

                movieDuration.setText(movie_durationz);
                movieYear.setText(movie_time);

                DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("Echo Shoow");
                ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
                Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);

                mVideoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(vidUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory,null,null);
            }

            initExoPlayer();

            if (mExoPlayerFullscreen) {
                ((ViewGroup) mExoPlayerView.getParent()).removeView(mExoPlayerView);
                mFullScreenDialog.addContentView(mExoPlayerView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                mFullScreenIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(DetailsActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_skrink));
                mFullScreenDialog.show();
            }
            // imageView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
            //  final String vidAddress = "https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4";
    //        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
    //        imageView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
    //        mPlayButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
    //        mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //            @Override
    //            public void onClick(View v) {
    //                imageView.start();
    //                // hide button once playback starts
    //                mPlayButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //            }
    //        });
    //        String fullScreen =  getIntent().getStringExtra("fullScreenInd");
    //        if("y".equals(fullScreen)) {
    //            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    //                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //            getSupportActionBar().hide();
    //        }
    //        vidControl = new MediaController(this);
    //        vidControl.setAnchorView(imageView);
            // imageView.setMediaController(vidControl);
            //imageView.setVideoURI("https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4","https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4");



            String base64EncodedPublicKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsNH7KIemSXJuQOaPQLpjEjLISNiAjNxnNoFeLIW7bYEqo+ODrg1ALBvxA0viiaidWnphuwfuORYruLSLcGTQrbPcNV1EYcxrDyrnt5W0Qcv+xgnTTMikuZPlAM+3wBQp7Neipudam1lN04WYrxaxWPtBYgw92cCGflxSJXPLwS5LEdIxFH7j9i6P+EiF0aBK29swIo0XvRnYHGn9aIMZ2lZMxMhFfR2mLoTt+inw7KGV0NTLoVSMPxFZuo9f+im8Uw73Ku2Xzf4KswV4D8Y6kJKr7cXwC7wFXIAGQoQbRsfptOUR8zmMYuGmOTi1FCZmBrfrR+JrXGNb4nnTqNx2YwIDAQAB";
            mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

            mHelper.startSetup(new
                                       IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                           public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                                               if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                                   Log.d(TAG1, "In-app Billing setup failed: " +
                                                           result);
                                               } else {
                                                   Log.d(TAG1, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                                               }
                                           }
                                       });
        }

    //    public void buttonClicked (View view)
    //    {
    //        clickButton.setEnabled(false);
    //        buyButton.setEnabled(true);
    //    }

        public void buyClick(View view) {

            if(movie_name.equals("Temba 1")||movie_name.equals("تمبة 1"))
            {
                ITEM_SKU=ITEM_SKU_temba1;
            }
            if(movie_name.equals("Temba 2")||movie_name.equals("تمبة 2"))
            {
                ITEM_SKU=ITEM_SKU_temba2;
            }
            if(movie_name.equals("Temba 3")||movie_name.equals("تمبة 3"))
            {
                ITEM_SKU=ITEM_SKU_temba3;
            }
            if(movie_name.equals("Dinar")||movie_name.equals("دينار"))
            {
                ITEM_SKU=ITEM_SKU_Dinar;
            }
            if(movie_name.equals("Malhamat Ghadr")||movie_name.equals("ملحمة الغدر"))
            {
                ITEM_SKU=ITEM_SKU_Malhamat_Ghadr;
            }
            if(movie_name.equals("Soukout Khilafa")||movie_name.equals("سقوط الخلافة"))
            {
                ITEM_SKU=ITEM_SKU_Soukout_Khilafa;
            }
            if(movie_name.equals("Malhamat Dhad")||movie_name.equals("ملحمة الضاد"))
            {
                ITEM_SKU=ITEM_SKU_Malhamat_Dhad;
            }
            if(movie_name.equals("Sawalef")||movie_name.equals("سوالف بوبخيت"))
            {
                ITEM_SKU=ITEM_SKU_Swalef;
            }
            if(movie_name.equals("Arab Twit")||movie_name.equals("عرب تويت"))
            {
                ITEM_SKU=ITEM_SKU_Arab_Twit;
            }
            if(movie_name.equals("Khaybar")||movie_name.equals("خيبر"))
            {
                ITEM_SKU=ITEM_SKU_Khaybar;
            }
            if(movie_name.equals("Malhamt Sakhra")||movie_name.equals("ملحمة صخرة"))
            {
                ITEM_SKU=ITEM_SKU_Malhamt_Sakhra;
            }


            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
                    mPurchaseFinishedListener, "purchase_token");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ITEM_SKU.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                        Intent data)
        {
            if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
                    resultCode, data)) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

        IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
                = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                              Purchase purchase)
            {
                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    // Handle error
                    return;
                }
                else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
                    consumeItem();
                    buyButton.setEnabled(false);
                }

            }
        };
        public void consumeItem() {
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
        }

        IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
                = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
            public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                                 Inventory inventory) {

                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    // Handle failure
                } else {
                    mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                            mConsumeFinishedListener);
                }
            }
        };

        IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
                new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
                    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                                  IabResult result) {

                        if (result.isSuccess()) {
                            list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            // handle error
                        }
                    }
                };

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
            mHelper = null;
        }



        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

            outState.putInt(STATE_RESUME_WINDOW, mResumeWindow);
            outState.putLong(STATE_RESUME_POSITION, mResumePosition);
            outState.putBoolean(STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN, mExoPlayerFullscreen);

            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }


        private void initFullscreenDialog() {

            mFullScreenDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen) {
                public void onBackPressed() {
                    if (mExoPlayerFullscreen)
                        closeFullscreenDialog();
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            };
        }


        private void openFullscreenDialog() {

            ((ViewGroup) mExoPlayerView.getParent()).removeView(mExoPlayerView);
            mFullScreenDialog.addContentView(mExoPlayerView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            mFullScreenIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(DetailsActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_skrink));
            mExoPlayerFullscreen = true;
            // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
            mFullScreenDialog.show();
        }


        private void closeFullscreenDialog() {

            ((ViewGroup) mExoPlayerView.getParent()).removeView(mExoPlayerView);
            ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.video_frame)).addView(mExoPlayerView);
            mExoPlayerFullscreen = false;
            mFullScreenDialog.dismiss();
            // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            mFullScreenIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(DetailsActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_expand));
        }


        private void initFullscreenButton() {

            PlaybackControlView controlView = (PlaybackControlView) mExoPlayerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_controller);
            mFullScreenIcon = (ImageView) controlView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_icon);
            mFullScreenButton = (FrameLayout) controlView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_button);
            mFullScreenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!mExoPlayerFullscreen) {
                        openFullscreenDialog();
                        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    }else {
                        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                        closeFullscreenDialog();}
                }
            });
        }


        private void initExoPlayer() {

            BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
            TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
            TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
            LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
            SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(this), trackSelector, loadControl);
            mExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

            boolean haveResumePosition = mResumeWindow != C.INDEX_UNSET;

            if (haveResumePosition) {
                mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().seekTo(mResumeWindow, mResumePosition);
            }

            mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().prepare(mVideoSource);
            mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onResume() {

            super.onResume();


        }


        @Override
        protected void onPause() {

            super.onPause();

            if (mExoPlayerView != null && mExoPlayerView.getPlayer() != null) {
                mResumeWindow = mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().getCurrentWindowIndex();
                mResumePosition = Math.max(0, mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().getContentPosition());

                mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().release();
            }

            if (mFullScreenDialog != null)
                mFullScreenDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
```

Comment: You can save a boolean (true) value in your SharedPreferences when a user buys the video. And make a check in the onCreate() method for this value and do the respective operation.

Comment: ok can you elaborate more please, i mean can you tell me how to make in my code because i am new to in-app billing and shared-preferences.

Comment: Non-consumables are tracked by Google and should be in your inventory. No need to save to preferences.

Comment: Save to a persistent layeur, such SQLite or SharedPreferences (if all your data is fixed), and you can restore all purchases trough InAppBilling API

Comment: ok in my case why it is not tracked by Google

Answer (score 0):

Make a button "BUY" and when user taps on that button, use following code

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("my_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.edit().putBoolean("key_video_buy", true).apply();
```

And in your `onCreate()` method, use this code

```
boolean videoBought = getSharedPreferences("my_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean"key_video_buy", false);
if (videoBought){
    ... //user bought the video already
}
else {
... //user hasn't bought it yet
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i am not successful in adding the shared preferences.

Comment: @ZKhan I didn't get what you said. Tell me where you got stuck.

Comment: please can you implement the whole shared preference method which you are suggesting according to my code because when i purchase the video once and close the application so the video is again need to paid.

Comment: Please learn SharedPreferences first and then you can understand the above code.

Comment: yeah i have idea about SharedPreferences but this one is complicated thats   why i am stucked. Can you please do it for me if possible for you because i am stucked from 3 days.

Comment: i am getting error in this line of code                                                   
    boolean videoBought = getSharedPreferences("my_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);.getBoolean"key_video_buy", false);

Comment: Fixed it. Didn't see I used a semicolon earlier. Again use the code. It will work now.

Comment: ok thank you but i have one thing that now shared preferences is saved for only one video. I mean when i buy one video but if i buy second video the shared preferences of first video get disappeared and its become again paid.

Comment: @ZKhan For that you have to create different keys for different videos and retrieve according to that. It seems to me that you still don't know how to use `SharedPreferences`. Please go through a tutorial before preceding.